# Repositioning interactive advertisements in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I've added advertisements by interactive in my app like so:

```
local ads = require("ads")
local adNetwork = "inneractive"
ads.init(adNetwork, "test_id")

local function displayAd()
ads.show("banner", {x=0,y=0, interval=30})
end
```

Then I call displayAd() in local function scene:enterScene(event) method. This works okay. Now, from the current class (game.lua), there are two scenes it can go to: gameover.lua and stage.lua. If the player clears the stage, it goes to the stage clear.

Now, if the stage clear scene appears, I'd like to move the advertisement's y-position to something like y=display.contentCenterY so I tried something like this on displayAd():

```
if adFlag == true then
     ads.show("banner", {x=0,y=0, interval=30})
elseif adFlag == false then
     ads.show("banner", {x=0,y=display.contentCenterY, interval=30})
end
```

The problem with this is that the advertisement only moves once game.lua is recalled and it never goes back to it's original position. I can't put it on the stage clear class because it has a time delay and automatically goes to the next stage. So my question is, how can I move my advertisement's position immediately on the next page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to modify your code like this:

```
if adFlag == true then
     ads.hide()
     ads.show("banner", {x=0,y=0, interval=30})
elseif adFlag == false then
     ads.hide()
     ads.show("banner", {x=0,y=display.contentCenterY, interval=30})
end
```